# Setting ROOT_URL for Review Apps

Tags: heroku, meteor

I created a Heroku pipeline and set up Review Apps, such that it creates one app per PR.

With Meteor (and I think with Rails) one needs to set ROOT_URL -- e.g. ROOT_URL=https://foo-prod.herokuapp.com. I can do this once for the prod version of the app, but review apps generate new names every time.

I tried to put this in my app.json, but it doesn't seem to have an effect:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "export ROOT_URL=https://$HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com"
  }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but I'd like to share what the Heroku team had to say on this, in case it's helpful to anybody out there. Your mileage may vary - I didn't try this as I ran into a number of other issues with Heroku Review Apps.

=======

You're getting close with solving the ROOT_URL issue by the looks of it. If you add HEROKU_APP_NAME as a required variable in your app.json, it'll automatically be set when we spin up the review app. If you then add a .profile.d script that picks it up and sets the ROOT_URL you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984025/how-to-set-env-var-in-heroku-preview-app-postdeploy-script/42959235#42959235) and has my answer on it.

Basically you can use the Heroku PlatformAPI using the API token set as an ENV var from the app.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, I solved it based on Chris's answer, by creating a .profile.d folder in the project root and adding a set_host.sh script (make sure to set permissions to executable) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${HEROKU_APP_NAME}" ]]; then
  export ROOT_URL="www.default-domain.com"
else
  export ROOT_URL=${HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com
fi
```