# Set host name as an environment variable in Heroku review app

Tags: heroku

I'm using the Review Apps feature integrated with Github on Heroku. In one of my apps, I set an environment variable called `HOST_NAME` . For example, if the site is http://www.purplebinder.com, then `HOST_NAME` would be set to `www.purplebinder.com`. It's used in a couple of places where we work with cookies and in our transactional emails.

When I open up a new pull request and spin up a review app, `HOST_NAME` should be something like `purplebinder-pr-27.herokuapp.com`.

Is there a way to set this value automatically? The [Heroku documentation on review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) says an env var can inherit a value from the parent app or be hardcoded in `app.json`. Neither of those approaches work here, because the value needs to be different each time, and also different from the parent app.

Heroku also says an env var can be set "through a generator", but doesn't go into detail about what that is.

This question might be a duplicate of [Setting ROOT_URL for Review Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254039/setting-root-url-for-review-apps), but nobody answered that one. It's also similar to [How to get Heroku app name from inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570579/how-to-get-heroku-app-name-url-from-inside-the-app), but the answers there involved running a script after the app was created - here I'd like to set this value as part of the initial build.

Comment: Struggling with the same thing currently -- And I'd argue that the chosen answer below doesn't actually answer the question, since `HEROKU_APP_NAME` will be `purplebinder-pr-27` in your case, not the full URL.

I also found this which gives an explanation of the "generator" comment in the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#heroku_app_name-and-heroku_parent_app_name:

> To help with scripting, two special config vars are available to
>   review apps. If you specify `HEROKU_APP_NAME` or `HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME`
>   as required or optional config vars in your `app.json` file, Heroku will
>   set those config vars to the new application name and the parent
>   application name respectively. They will then be available for use in
>   the postdeploy script so that you can do more advanced bootstrapping
>   and configuration.
>
> Here is an example `app.json` file that uses
>   `HEROKU_APP_NAME` and `HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME`:
>
> ```
> {
>     "name":"Advanced App",
>     "scripts": {
>         "postdeploy": "rake db:setup && bin/bootstrap"
>     },
>     "env": {
>         "HEROKU_APP_NAME": {
>             "required": true
>         },
>         "HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME": {
>             "required": true
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: FYI, `HEROKU_APP_NAME` is just the name. ie `my-app` not `my-app.herokuapp.com` so you'll have to manually append the rest `.herokuapp.com` to get a usable URL.

Comment: what's the content of `bin/bootstrap` in this example? I can't seem to set heroku ENV variables from within the app.

Comment: Does not work. Also, why does nobody explain about the purpose of `"postdeploy": "rake db:setup && bin/bootstrap"` line? Is it a necessary line? Tried it in my server, and does not work.

Comment: The `postdeploy` line in that example is pointless. If that entry said `"postdeploy": "echo $HEROKU_APP_NAME"` it would help convey the idea that the env variable would be accessible within the `postdeploy` step.

Answer (score 6):

If you add the [heroku-buildpack-cli](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli) to your parent app, then it enables you to set environment variables from your [post-deploy script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-postdeploy-script). The command should look something like the following:

```
heroku config:set HOST_NAME=${HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com --app ${HEROKU_APP_NAME}
```

Comment: I couldn't do this since you need to `heroku login` in the postdeploy script to authenticate the cli first.

Comment: For those landing here looking to authenticate with the cli buildpack, the notes section on the repo has the answer: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli#notes the solution is to create a temporary auth token inline with the postdeploy entry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach ignoring `app.json` for Rails installations:

in the relative `config/<environment>.rb`. I personally use `production.rb` and staging just references it.

```
if ENV.fetch("HEROKU_APP_NAME", "").include?("staging-pr-")
  ENV["APPLICATION_HOST"] = ENV["HEROKU_APP_NAME"] + ".herokuapp.com"
  ENV["ASSET_HOST"] = "https://" + ENV["APPLICATION_HOST"]
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV.fetch("APPLICATION_HOST") }
end
...
```

It's a bit misleading as the heroku environment variables will still have the old variables, but it works.

Comment: Don't you have to also add HEROKU_APP_NAME and HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME in the app.json for them to be decalred in your ruby scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `review` environment for you application copying `staging.rb` or `production.rb` from `config/environments`. This would be useful.

After adding `HEROKU_APP_NAME` and `HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME` to your `app.json`, you can easily set;

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "#{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}.herokuapp.com" }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://#{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}.herokuapp.com"
config.action_controller.asset_host = "#{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}.herokuapp.com"
config.action_cable.url = "wss://#{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}.herokuapp.com/cable"
```

Comment: This approach is not recommended by heroku.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon can you add a link/reference as to why it's not recommended by Heroku? curious what the reasons are. Thanks!

Comment: I read it from the heroku documentation itself,  so i basically followed the documentation and found another solution.  It was a long time ago,  so i don't have the link handy