# How to set ENV var in Heroku preview app postdeploy script

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

I want to set the `HOST` env var to `$HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapps.com` on a preview app.  It doesn't look like I can do this in `app.json` since this is a computed value.

I was hoping to do it in a "postdeploy" script like this

```
heroku config:set HOST="`heroku config:get HEROKU_APP_NAME -a neon-dev-pr-520`.herokuapps.com"
```

but it wants to authenticate me as a Heroku user.  Alas, this doesn't work either:

```
export HOST=$HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapps.com
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I found [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190421170934/www.lifeinspect.com/heroku/ruby/rails/2015/11/26/setting-heroku-apps-url-in-review-app.html) which suggests that you can use the Heroku PlatformAPI.

In this case as a Rails Rake task which is run as the postdeploy:

```ruby
desc 'Bootstrap review app'
task bootstrap: ['db:schema:load', 'db:seed'] do
  heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth(ENV['HEROKU_API_TOKEN'])
  heroku.config_var.update(ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME'], 'WWW_HOSTNAME' => "#{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}.herokuapp.com")
end
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works! There are some additional steps that are necessary (installing platform-api gem, generating a token, and adding it to your ENV on staging) but I added additional instructions

Comment: Additional instructions and an updated link were rejected as an edit for some reason. Here's the good link: https://www.lifeinspect.com/heroku/ruby/rails/2015/11/26/setting-heroku-apps-url-in-review-app.html I also added the additional instructions there

Comment: Thanks @JayDorsey not sure why it was rejected, maybe requests time out. I've updated the link in the OP.

Comment: @JayDorsey Thanks for extra details. How did you generate a token? More precisely, were you able to generate it programmatically? Trying to generate short-lived tokens that will expire soon after config_var is updated

Comment: @mizurnix you should be able to generate tokens that expire at a specific time per [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-authorizations-create) using the `--expires-in=` flag

Comment: @JayDorsey Thanks for the answer. I had a bit different thing in mind though: is there a way to automate token generation so that each time a new review app is created, a short lived token is also created and it expires soon after the job is done. No humans involved in the process. I am after reducing potential security concerns because according to me, Heroku tokens are way too permissive and I am not comfortable with them living forever in pipeline settings

Comment: @mizurnix I think that's still doable reading the docs (I haven't done it). You might be able to create a long-lived auth/token (maybe with only token create perms?), and then use that token to create short-lived tokens to modify env vars. I haven't done it before, I'm just looking at the auth: docs on the page I linked above. Either way, you're going to have to have some kind of long-running persisted token somewhere. If security is paramount you'll need to use some kind of secure key value store (rather than an ENV)

Answer (score 4):

Worked out with the assistance of Heroku's awesome support team a few years ago. We needed to set a reflexive environment variable for a middleware (parse-server) to know what to connect to. It's set manually on our Staging and Production apps, but to get it set on our review apps:

My app.json incldues:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "bin/bootstrap"
  },
...
  "env": {
    "HEROKU_APP_NAME": {
      "required": true
    },
    "HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME": {
      "required": true
    },
...
```

bin/bootstrap is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $HEROKU_APP_NAME
export SERVER_URL=https://$HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/parse
```

`SERVER_URL` is available (and correct) in my review apps. It's been no problems since we implemented.

Comment: This does not appear to work as of September 2020. Just tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for review apps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#heroku_app_name-and-heroku_parent_app_name

As long as you declare `HEROKU_APP_NAME` or `HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME` as required or optional in your `app.json` file, they will be available for you to use in your postdeploy script so you can just do:

```
HOST="$HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com"
```

Comment: excellent, thank you!  In case it helps anyone else finding this, same thing goes for other env vars you might like to set.  **tldr; the environment variables you set in the postdeploy script in your app.json file seem to stay set in the review app**

Comment: ^^ Scratch that-- after testing this out in practice, doesn't seem like this is the case, at least as of Jun 22, 2018.  (In case this matters, as a data point, I am using multiple buildpacks.)

Answer (score 0):

Using python requests within a postdeploy script:

```
import requests
result = requests.patch(f"https://api.heroku.com/apps/{os.environ.get('HEROKU_APP_NAME')}/config-vars",
                   data=json.dumps({"YOUR_KEY": "SOME_VALUE"}),
                   headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
```

"Authorization": f"Bearer {os.environ.get("HEROKU_API_KEY")}"}
                       )

Or using curl when logged:

```
  curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/config-vars \
  -d '{
  "FOO": "bar",
  "BAZ": "qux"
}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

And when not logged in add the header, where an app token has been generated:

```
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $HEROKU_API_KEY"
```

- https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#netrc-authentication
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#curl-examples